# favicon doesnot display in react application browser tab

Tags: reactjs, webpack, favicon

I want to display favicon in the browser tab for my react application. Below are the steps i followed to do so:
1. Generated favicon package, downloaded and copied all favicons into the public/static/images folder.
2. My index.html file is outside the public folder. but both public and index.html reside in same folder. I have added the lines below in the head section of index.html file.

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-touch- 
 icon.png"> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon- 
 32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon- 
 16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/site.webmanifest">
 <link rel="mask-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/safari-pinned-tab.svg" 
 color="#5bbad5">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I run the application in the browser with this url localhost:3000 and the console gives me error "URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png'" and in the browser tab i see this this http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png when i click on the console error for more information.

Am i missing some steps here. Could someone help me solving this. I have no clue how to proceed further. Thanks.

Edited: Also using webpack. so do i need to make some changes in webpack-config.js file? If so could someone provide some insight into this.thanks.

Comment: `%PUBLIC_URL%` is meant to be replaced during the build process with whatever value you specified in your build configuration. Also, stick with `.ico` files, they have a wider support (and use `rel="shortcut icon"` when linking them).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on %PUBLIC_URL% point. i have included favicon.ico (<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">) thanks

Comment: try `%PUBLIC_URL%/static/images/favicon-32x32.png`

Comment: thanks. tried and i get the URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/static/images/favicon-32x32.png'

Comment: replaced %PUBLIC_URL% with the build configuration and it works thanks.